# How to use JCheckBox to make JTextField editable and vice versa?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jcheckbox

I am writing an application in Java and am using Netbeans IDE. I have set two `JCheckBox` (`chk1` and `chk2`) and  two `JTextField` (`jtextfield1` and `jtextfield2`). I want that if I check `chk1`, `jtextfield2` will be set to uneditable and if I `chk2`, `jtextfield2` will be set to editable and vice versa.

How to use JCheckBox to make JTextField editable and vice versa?

With the code below, it works alright but if i check the `chk2` all the text fields are set to uneditable.

```
private void ckDepoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

   if(ckDepo.isSelected()){
   txtDeposit.setEditable(false);
   }
   else{

   txtWithdraw.setEditable(true);
   }

}                                      

private void ckWithdrawActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    transact="withdraw";
    if(ckWithdraw.isSelected()){
   txtWithdraw.setEditable(false);
   }
    else{
   txtDeposit.setEditable(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: You should use JRadioButtons and a ButtonGroup, not JCheckBoxes.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [How to use buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels i tried the JRadioButtons and a buttonGroup and still didnt work

Comment: poster, think about your last statement from our point of view. Can you see how we have no idea what you could possibly be doing wrong based on what you've posted? If you still need help, show your latest code as an edit to your question and provide enough detailed information so we can understand what might not be working for you. As you can see from my answer below, it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

- I would use JRadioButtons all added to the same ButtonGroup. This way selecting one JRadioButton will unselect all the others.
- I would give each JRadioButton an ItemListener that inside it enabled or disabled its adjacent JTextField.

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class RadioBtnMayhem {
   private static final int COLUMNS = 10;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
      ButtonGroup btnGroup = new ButtonGroup();
      int fieldCount = 5;
      for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++) {
         JRadioButton radioBtn = new JRadioButton();
         btnGroup.add(radioBtn);
         final JTextField textField = new JTextField(COLUMNS);
         textField.setEnabled(false);
         radioBtn.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
               textField.setEnabled(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED);
            }
         });

         JPanel radioFieldPanel = new JPanel();
         radioFieldPanel.add(radioBtn);
         radioFieldPanel.add(textField);

         mainPanel.add(radioFieldPanel);
      }

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mainPanel);
   }
}
```